# Bootstrap bootsnipp advanced search layout bug on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a bootstrap bootsnipp code, unfortunately on mobile the layout doesn't look that good and the search button drops under the text box. It looks great on desk top. Any ideas how to make the input elements stay together on mobile?

I have cleaned this up and you can view the source at: http://allthings.trade/dev/bootstrapas/advancedfind.html

Comment: what is the issue then? please describe little bit more about your issue..as text box will be above then search bar according to your code then?

Comment: In a desktop it all the controls (text box, drop down button and search button) are aligned horizontally as I wan them to. When I open the page on a mobile the the search button appears under the text box. I noticed playing with the css that the display flex may have something to do with the issue, as when I remove that, the desk top has the same issue that mobile.

Comment: so did you resolved your issue or you don't want search box under the text box..it should above the text box?

Comment: i haven't been able to resolve it. I would like them to all stay lined up. I don't want the search button to drop down. Any ideas?